# iOS Protocol Method Not Called with Storyboard Segue

Tags: ios, delegates, segue

I'm passing an array back from one view controller to another.

I'm doing this using protocol and delegate.

The issue i'm facing is if I use the prepareForSegue method that delegate method is not called. But if i create a custom button then use

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:bController animated:YES];
```

on going back to the view controller where I'm passing that array to the method is accessed.

How do i resolve this? i.e. If i place the following chunk of code into my custom next button, how do i identify that word segue (which comes from prepareFromSegue)?

```
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"page2topage3"]){ ... }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have defined a delegate property in ViewController A and you want ViewController B to act as a delegate to A.
Then `instanceOfViewControllerA.delegate = instanceOfViewControllerB.`

In Storyboard, lets say you are going from A to B through segue.

In `prepareForSegue` method in `ViewControllerA` class,

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    ViewControllerB *instanceOfViewControllerB = segue.destinationViewController;
    self.delegate = instanceOfViewControllerB;
}
```

Comment: Awesome mate - that was it ! Cheers. I just needed to add instanceOfViewControllerB.self = delegate.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)doneButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:kFromCardListToCardDetailViewControllerIdentifier sender:self];
}

#pragma mark - segue methods

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:kFromCardListToCardDetailViewControllerIdentifier]) {
        MyCardViewController *cardViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        cardViewController.card = self.cardArray[self.lastSelectedRow];
    }
}
```